# Changing enum value of struct in iterator

Tags: rust, iterator, closures, ownership, borrowing

```rust
pub struct Server {
  devices: Vec<Device>,
}

pub struct Device {
  configuration: Configuration,
}

pub enum Configuration {
    Gradient {
        stops: Vec<String>,
        brightness: f32,
        duration: i32,
        random_starting_point: bool,
    },
}
```

I want to update the configurations of certain devices dynamically through the method:

```rust
fn update_configuration(&mut self, devices: Vec<Device>, configuration: Configuration) {
    self.devices
        .iter_mut()
        .filter(|device| devices.contains(device.get_id()))
        .for_each(|device| {
            (*device).configuration = configuration;
        });
}
```

The compiler outputs:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `configuration`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure

device.update_configuration(configuration);
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `configuration` has type `device::Configuration`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

And since I have a `Vec<String>` in that enum value I can't implement the `Copy` trait. I do have a basic understanding of memory management (stack, heap) and pointers but I can't quite wrap my head around it completely.

**My questions**

- How do I achieve such a field change?
- Is this the idiomatic way to update such a field in a struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rust every piece of data can have at most 1 unique owner. You're taking a single instance of `Configuration` and trying to share it across potentially multiple `Device`s. The simplest way to solve your problem would be to derive an implementation of `Clone` which will allow you to make clones of the `Configuration` enum whenever you try to share it.

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
pub enum Configuration {}
```

And then clone it in your loop:

```rust
self.devices
    .iter_mut()
    .filter(|device| devices.contains(device.get_id()))
    .for_each(|device| {
        (*device).configuration = configuration.clone();
    });
```

Note: this will give a unique clone of `Configuration` to every `Device` which is what I'm assuming you want.